# How to wait for Postgres to be ready before loading data in Docker Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
    pg-data:

services:
    db:
        image: postgis/postgis
        build: ./postgis

        volumes: 
            - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql

        ports: 
            - 5432:5432

        restart: on-failure
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM postgis/postgis

USER root

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY data_load.sh /data_load.sh
RUN chmod +x /*.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

My `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
exec /data_load.sh &
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

My `data_load.sh`:

```
until pg_isready -h localhost -p 5432
do
    printf 'PostgreSQL not ready! \n'
    sleep 15
done

echo "Loading data"
python /load_data.py &&
echo "Data load complete!"
```

When running `docker-compose up --build` I get:

```
...
Successfully built 88b291d6b47e
Successfully tagged postgis/postgis:latest
Creating my_compose_db_1 ... done
Attaching to my_compose_db_1
db_1  | Starting script to add data
db_1  | localhost:5432 - no response
db_1  | PostgreSQL not ready yet, trying again in 15 seconds
```

The problem is Postgres never starts! The data_load.sh script executes as I can see the 'PostgreSQL is not ready!' printed out every 15 seconds. Ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script setup you have, nothing ever runs the base image's entrypoint.  You provide your own script as `/docker-entrypoint.sh`, which concludes by re-running itself.  (The `postgres` base image [puts its entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/88173efa530f1a174a7ea311c5b6ee5e383f68bd/12/Dockerfile#L183) in `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`.)

For a PostgreSQL derived image, a much simpler setup will work.  At first initialization, the standard `postgres` image will run any `*.sql` or `*.sh` scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, and you're guaranteed that the database is running at that particular point.  So if you reduce the loader script to just

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec /load_data.py
```

and copy that into the right directory

```sh
FROM postgis/postgis
COPY data_load.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data_load.sh
COPY load_data.py /load_data.py
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data_load.sh /load_data.py
# And use the base image's ENTRYPOINT/CMD
```

you don't need to write this scripting by hand at all.

If the script is a more involved database-seeding job, it's also reasonable to run it from a totally separate Docker container, or using of your application's database migration system.  (Since schemas do change occasionally, it's probably better to limit the database-local setup to creating initial users and databases and leaving the rest to your application code.)